# Change bit state in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia language how can one set, clear and reverse a single bit? I hope you won't consider this question out of scope or too broad; if so, please comment it instead of downvote it.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 6):

Having this paragraph from Julia-Lang doc:

> Currently, only sizes that are multiples of 8 bits are supported.
>   Therefore, boolean values, although they really need just a single
>   bit, cannot be declared to be any smaller than eight bits.

First it's possible to take a look at the binary representation of a variable like this:

```
julia> bits(Int(10)) 
"00000000000000000000000000001010"
```

and secondly, one can create byte value directly using its binary form:

```
julia> val=0b100
0x04

julia> typeof(val)
UInt8
```

and lastly, the best way to change value of a bit is performing right binary operation on its byte value:

```
julia> val | 0b10 # set 2nd bit
0x06

julia> bits(ans)
"00000110"

julia> val & 0b11111011 # clear 3nd bit
0x00
```

Comment: `bitstring` should be used now instead of `bits`.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are wanting to *clear*, *set* and *check* the states of specific bits in a byte.

Where:

- `N` represents the integer in question and;
- `n` is the number of the bit in question (i.e: the `n`-th bit) and;
- the LSB is `1`-th bit

---

- **set** the n-th bit: `N |= 2^(n-1)`
- **clear** the n-th bit: `N &= ~(2^(n-1))`
- **check** the state of a bit by copying and shifting: `(N >> (n-1)) & 1 != 0`
- **check** the state of a bit using a bit-mask: `mask = 2^(n-1); N & mask != mask`
- **reverse**/**toggle**/**invert** the n-th bit, using [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table): `N ⊻= 2^(n-1)`. The `xor` function may also be used.

Comment: change `2^n` to `1<<n` can be much faster